# keep ghostscript running - even if fed garbage

Tags: python, windows, ghostscript

**Short version**:  how can I tell ghostscript, "keep going, even if you find garbage" when running in batch mode?

**Longer version**:  I have a bit of Python code on Windows that uses check_subprocess to call Ghostcript.  (I'm merging several PDFs into one).

```
popenargs = [r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin64.exe'
,'-dBATCH'
,'-dNOPAUSE'
,'-dLastPage=5'
,'-q'
,'-sDEVICE=pdfwrite'
,r'-sOutputFile=C:\temp\bar.pdf'
,r'c:\temp\a.pdf',r'c:\temp\b.pdf']

subprocess.check_call(args)
```

While things are running, you see the Ghostcript window pop up and disappear, and that's OK with me.

The problem occurs when ghostscript encounters a corrupted PDF.  It leaves the window up, with some details about the error, and instructions to close the window manually. This is problematic, because it leaves the python script hanging.  I don't want that -- if an error is found, that's OK with me -- I just want the file skipped and for things to keep moving.

Is there any way to tell Ghostscript to do what I want?

Comment: Is there a chance to use python PDF-tools for the page re-assembly tasks and have thus the process under a better control-loop/remedy-provisioning, than trying to salvage an external process that started to panic?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see an example to say for sure, but the simple answer (on Windows) is no.

You could, of course, use gswin64c.exe instead, its much more suitable for automation anyway.